# How to generate a JaCoCo report with JUnit platform launcher?

Tags: java, junit, junit5, jacoco

I am currently building automated tests which will be generated dynamically in their own class (e.g. TestClass1234567890.class). From those tests (which I will run with the JUnit Platform Launcher) I want to generate a JaCoCo rapport.

Whenever I look up examples for the JaCoCo API, they only show it with a class that implements Runnable, which does not make sense since you'd want to run it on a test class.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction on how to combine the JaCoCo API with the JUnit Platform Launcher? Any resource/example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You use jacoco report maven plugin:

> org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.7-SNAPSHOT:report

together with its optional parameters you could define how do you like it

[check here](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-mojo.html)